# LocationValueError when using python requests module

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I have been using the requests package to interact with the web and had no issues in the past. Recently when using a script that I haven't used for about a week I encountered the following error while doing a routine `requests.get()` call:

```
LocationValueError: No host specified.
```

## Background Research

After a lot of googling various permutations of `python requests LocationValueError`, `python requests no host error` and `python urllib3 LocationValueError` (according to the stack trace the error is raised by `urllib3` which requests uses underneath) I only managed to find this information buried in the `urllib3` documentation:

> exception urllib3.exceptions.LocationValueError
>
> Raised when there is something wrong with a given URL input.

## What I've tried

Thinking something might be wrong with my version of the requests package as this is arguably one of the most basic calls used in the requests package I did the following:

- Reinstalled requests
- Created a virtual environment and installed requests using pip
- Installed requests from source
- Installing urllib3 expicitly
- Installed python 3.4 from source then tried that (I use python3.5 at the moment)

In all instances I used the following code to see whether requests was still throwing the LocationValueError:

```
import requests
address = 'http://www.google.com/'    
requests.get(address)
```

Which has always worked in the past. I checked on a different computer (an ubuntu laptop) and it works there, leading me to think that the issue is specific to my computer.

## Stack Trace of the Problem

Here is the stack trace I got when using requests installed in a virtualenv and with python3.4.

```
In [5]: import requests

In [6]: requests.get('http://www.google.com/')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
LocationValueError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
----> 1 requests.get('http://www.google.com/')

/home/michael/Documents/my_test_env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/requests/api.py in get(url, params, **kwargs)
     67 
     68     kwargs.setdefault('allow_redirects', True)
---> 69     return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
     70 
     71 

/home/michael/Documents/my_test_env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/requests/api.py in request(method, url, **kwargs)
     48 
     49     session = sessions.Session()
---> 50     response = session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
     51     # By explicitly closing the session, we avoid leaving sockets open which
     52     # can trigger a ResourceWarning in some cases, and look like a memory leak

/home/michael/Documents/my_test_env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/requests/sessions.py in request(self, method, url, params, data, headers, cookies, files, auth, timeout, allow_redirects, proxies, hooks, stream, verify, cert, json)
    466         }
    467         send_kwargs.update(settings)
--> 468         resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
    469 
    470         return resp

/home/michael/Documents/my_test_env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/requests/sessions.py in send(self, request, **kwargs)
    574 
    575         # Send the request
--> 576         r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
    577 
    578         # Total elapsed time of the request (approximately)

/home/michael/Documents/my_test_env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/requests/adapters.py in send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
    335         """
    336 
--> 337         conn = self.get_connection(request.url, proxies)
    338 
    339         self.cert_verify(conn, request.url, verify, cert)

/home/michael/Documents/my_test_env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/requests/adapters.py in get_connection(self, url, proxies)
    247             proxy = prepend_scheme_if_needed(proxy, 'http')
    248             proxy_manager = self.proxy_manager_for(proxy)
--> 249             conn = proxy_manager.connection_from_url(url)
    250         else:
    251             # Only scheme should be lower case

/home/michael/Documents/my_test_env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/poolmanager.py in connection_from_url(self, url)
    137         """
    138         u = parse_url(url)
--> 139         return self.connection_from_host(u.host, port=u.port, scheme=u.scheme)
    140 
    141     def urlopen(self, method, url, redirect=True, **kw):

/home/michael/Documents/my_test_env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/poolmanager.py in connection_from_host(self, host, port, scheme)
    246 
    247         return super(ProxyManager, self).connection_from_host(
--> 248             self.proxy.host, self.proxy.port, self.proxy.scheme)
    249 
    250     def _set_proxy_headers(self, url, headers=None):

/home/michael/Documents/my_test_env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/poolmanager.py in connection_from_host(self, host, port, scheme)
    108 
    109         if not host:
--> 110             raise LocationValueError("No host specified.")
    111 
    112         scheme = scheme or 'http'

LocationValueError: No host specified.
```

If anyone can help explain the cause of the error or point me in the right direction that'd be most appreciated. This issue also happens when I'm using a request.Session object to get pages for an extended session.

Comment: do you have any local dns configurations? like custom `hosts` or something? proxy? firewall?

Comment: I've used a VPN in the past but I still get the error even when it's deactivated. Other than that I haven't changed the network configuration since I installed my OS.

Comment: Can you make a call using `urllib`? Asin, is this specific to `requests` module? And which OS are you using?

Answer (score 2):

For me, the problem was that the url I was requested did a redirect to *Location: https//*, which is possibly not valid, but which urllib3 couldn't handle.

Comment: how did you solve it ?